# Set theory equation with a Venn diagram.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone help me understand the answer to this set theory question?

Essentially, I read `(A n B)'` as everything that is not in A **and** B. Which would make sense why only the intersecting area of the circles is not included.

However, I read `(A' u B')` as everything not in A **or** not in B, which to me would mean elements not in circle A, not in circle B, and not in both. Similar to how logic gates work in electronics, where **or** would mean 'one or the other, or both'.

So can anyone explain how `(A' u B')` satisfies the following shaded area? Why are the singular sections of A and B included? I would have thought this equation only highlights the outside of the circles `Ω`.

*Note: Im not disputing the answer, I know its correct, I just can't visualise why.*

[image]

Comment: $\cup$ (set union) is exactly like "or": $A \cup B$ means "either in $A$ or in $B$". Thus, $A' \cup B'$ means "either in not-$A$ or in not-$B$".

Comment: It might help to draw the diagrams for $A'$ and for $B'$ before trying to draw one for $A'\cup B'$.

Comment: In the first case: $(A \cap B)'$ the diagram shades all the area except for the intersection (what is both in $A$ and in $B$).

Comment: In the second case: $(A' \cup B')$, the diagram **must** shade what is either outside $A$ (and thus also the part of $B$ not intersecting $A$) or outside $B$ (and thus...). The intersection is again not shaded because it isnot outside $A$ not outside $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Bcomplement]

$B'$ is the purple area.

[image: Acomplement]

$A'$ is the green-blue area.

$A'\cup B'=\Omega\setminus (A\cap B)=(A\cap B)'$.

Comment: Thanks! All answers here helped me understand this, yours was the one that visually demonstrated this, so I have accepted. I was reading the formula as a whole and not taking into consideration A' & B' individually.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the universe $\Omega$ is $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and we have $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$.

Then $A \cap B = \{2\}$ and $(A \cap B)' = \{1,3,4\}$.

Also $A' = \{3,4\}$, $B'=\{1,4\}$ and so $A' \cup B' = \{1,3,4\}$ too.

$1 \in A' \cup B'$ because $1 \in B'$. So even though $1$ is also a member of $A$, it can still be a member of $A' \cup B'$. Similarly, $3 \in A' \cup B'$ because $3 \in A'$, even though $3$ is also a member of $B$.

The sub-set of $\Omega$ that is in neither $A$ nor in $B$ is denoted by $A' \cap B'$. In this example $A' \cap B' = \{4\}$.